# Can I make a link point to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is:

```
<input class="button"  type="button" value="Mark" onClick="doCheck('mark');" \>
```

I want to make it using an

```
<a>
```

link. Is it possible to do this? I only know how linking to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Like that

```
<a class="button"  href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="doCheck('mark');" >Mark</a>
```

or this way

```
<a class="button"  href="javascript:doCheck('mark')" >Mark</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`< a href='javascript:void(null);' onclick='doCheck()' > Test </a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onClick="doCheck('mark');"> Mark </a>
```

You can attach click handlers to any DOM element that is visible on the page. I would seperately recommend seperation of markup and javascript.

So something like.

```
<a id="mark">

...

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
     $("#mark").click(function() {
         doCheck("mark");
     });
});

</script>
```

Would be preferable. In this case `$` is [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/). A pure javascript solution is possible but that has a lot of boilerplate code that hides the point.

Comment: The tag needs a `href` attribute though, otherwise it won't be a link.

Answer (score 0):

This code example will execute the JavaScript without following the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doCheck('mark'); return false;">Mark</a>
```

If you want to follow the link, drop the `return false;` part:

```
<a href="somewhere.html" onclick="doCheck('mark');">Mark</a>
```

Comment: The tag needs a `href` attribute though, otherwise it won't be a link.

Comment: Both tags need a `href` attribute to be links, even if it's not used. Without the attribute the tag becomes a bookmark anchor instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClick attribute on any html element.  So use it in your `a` tag or in your `img` tag.